# Docker Container not able call REST API hosted in other server timeout error

Tags: docker, containers

**I am trying to call an api hosted in VM but it is always timeout, even trying to read from IOT hub same error is comming** 
An error occurred while sending the request.

## Audit trail of this API call:

- [1] BadRequest: Node: http://23.101.119.177:9200/ Took: 00:00:21.8719035

  ## OriginalException: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out

  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
  at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
  at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData) in C:\Users\russ\source\elasticsearch-net-master\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\HttpConnection-CoreFx.cs:line 73

  ## Request:

## Response:

Comment: Can you reach the remote from the host where the container is running?

Comment: I am testing this scenario from my local Docker container.

Comment: But if you cannot access via host, you probably won't be able to connect via docker container, that check would be just to confirm that this is docker container specific, and not a network connectivity between docker host and Rest API host.

Comment: Actually issue is my docker container app wants to make a call to external link. it is not able to call.